# virtual calls on overridden interface implementations

Tags: c#, interface, virtual

If I have two classes that both implement an interface, but also inherit, do I need to make the function virtual? eg given:

```
interface IDoSomething
{
    void DoSomething();
}

class A : IDoSomething
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //do A
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public new void DoSomething()
    {
        //do B
    }
}
```

Would the following code do A or B?

```
IDoSomething doer = new B();
doer.DoSomething(); //do A or do B?
```

I'm getting confused because I'm under the impression that all inteface calls are effectively virtual, but obviously I am using the new operator to hide the base definition.

Comment: Is the question A or B, or *why* A and not B? Because the first one you can answer yourself quite easily.

Comment: Yes, more why, sorry! Will edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3621456/1004522) is the explanation. Already available at stackoverflow forums.

> Quoting Jeffrey Ritcher from CLR via CSharp 3rd Edition here
>
> The CLR requires that interface methods be marked as virtual. If you
>   do not explicitly mark the method as virtual in your source code, the
>   compiler marks the method as virtual and sealed; this prevents a
>   derived class from overriding the interface method. If you explicitly
>   mark the method as virtual, the compiler marks the method as virtual
>   (and leaves it unsealed); this allows a derived class to override the
>   interface method. If an interface method is sealed, a derived class
>   cannot override the method. However, a derived class can re-inherit
>   the same interface and can provide its own implementation for the
>   interface’s methods.

Comment: Exactly the info I was looking for, thanks! I was even going to ask about re-inheriting the interface.

Answer (score 2):

```
class A : IDoSomething
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        //do A
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        //do B
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `leppie`'s solution.  If that's not an option:

```
class A : IDoSomething
{
    void IDoSomething.DoSomething()
    {
        //do A
    }
}

class B : A
{
    void IDoSomething.DoSomething()
    {
        //do B
    }
}
```

But note that this will hide the implementation, so you can't do `((A)doer).DoSomething()`.

If you can't change class A to either of these solutions, I don't think there's a sure way to override it in all cases.  You could both explicitly implement the interface and make a `public new` method on B.  That way if it's statically known as an `IDoSomething` or as a `B` it will use B's implementation, but if it's known as an `A` it will still use `A`'s implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Although C# and .net allow derived classes to re-implement interface methods, it is often better to have the base class use a virtual method to implement the interface, and have the derived class override that method, in any situation where a derived class might wish to augment, rather than entirely replace, the base-class implementation.  In some languages like vb.net, this can be done directly regardless of whether a class exposes a public member with the same name and signature as the interface member being implemented.  In other languages like C#, a public method which implements an interface can be marked unsealed and virtual (allowing a derived class to override it and have that override call `base.Member(params)` but an explicit interface implementation cannot.  In such languages, the best one can do is something like:

```
class MyClass : MyInterface
{
  void MyInterface.DoSomething(int param)
  {
    doSomething(param);
  }
  protected virtual void doSomething(int param)
  {
    ...
  }
}
class MyClass2 : MyClass
{
  protected override void doSomething(int param)
  {
    ...
    base.doSomething(param);
    ...
  }
}
```

In some cases, having the interface implementation wrap a virtual call can be advantageous, since it allows the base class to ensure that certain things happen before or after the overridden function.  For example, a non-virtual interface implementation of Dispose could wrap a virtual Dispose method:

```
  int DisposingFlag; // System.Boolean doesn't work with Interlocked.Exchange
  void IDisposable.Dispose()
  {
    if (Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(DisposingFlag, 1, 0) == 0)
    {
      Dispose(true);
      DisposingFlag = 2;
      Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier();
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
  }
  public bool Disposed { get {return (DisposingFlag != 0);} }
  public bool FullyDisposed { get {return (DisposingFlag > 1);} }
```

This will (unlike Microsoft's default wrapper) ensure that `Dispose` only gets called once, even if multiple threads try to call it simultaneously.  Further, it makes a `Disposed` property available.  Using Microsoft's wrapper, every derived class that wants a `Disposed` flag would have to define its own; even if the base-class `Disposed` flag were protected or public, it wouldn't be safe to use because it wouldn't get set until after derived classes had already begun cleanup.  Setting `DisposingFlag` within the wrapper avoids that problem.