# C# Interface Inheritance to Abstract class

Tags: c#, oop, interface, abstract-class, concrete

Suppose if I have an Interface as defined below:

```
public interface IFunctionality
{
    void Method();       
}
```

and I implement this interface for an abstract class as shown below:

```
public abstract class AbstractFunctionality: IFunctionality
{
    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Abstract stuff" + "\n");
    }       
}
```

again I have a concrete class which Inherits from abstract class as below:

```
public class ConcreteFunctionality: AbstractFunctionality
{
    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Concrete stuff" + "\n");
    }
}
```

Now I have the following code,

```
ConcreteFunctionality mostDerived = new ConcreteFunctionality();
AbstractFunctionality baseInst = mostDerived;
IFunctionality interfaceInst = mostDerived;
mostDerived.Method();
baseInst.Method();
interfaceInst.Method();
```

The output which I am getting after execution of this stuff is as following.

```
Concrete stuff
Abstract stuff
Abstract stuff
```

But what I have been expecting the output to be "Concrete Stuff" in all the three cases as what I am doing here is assigning the reference of `ConcreteFunctionality` to the variables of type `AbstractFunctionality` and `IFunctionality`.

What is happening internally. Kindly clarify.

Comment: This might clear something up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c

Comment: "It's hidden, not overridden" -- a good mantra to remember. (But your compiler should have mentioned this; do you have your warnings filtered out?)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Here:

```
public class ConreteFunctionality:AbstractFunctionality
{
    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Concrete stuff" + "\n");
    }
}
```

... you're not overriding the *existing* method. You're creating a *new* method which *hides* the existing one. (You should get a warning, too, suggesting the use of the `new` modifier if you really want this behaviour.) The interface was implemented in `AbstractFunctionality`, so the interface mapping table refers to the method in that class.

Now if you *reimplement* the interface:

```
public class ConcreteFunctionality : AbstractFunctionality, IFunctionality
```

... then the interface mapping will refer to the method in `ConcreteFunctionality` and you'll get the behaviour you expect for the call through the *interface* (i.e. your third call) but you'd still get the implementation in `AbstractFunctionality` for your second call.

It would be generally cleaner and more sanity-preserving to make the method in `AbstractFunctionality` virtual, and override it in `ConcreteFunctionality`. That way it will use the `ConcreteFunctionality` implementation in all cases.

Comment: That wouldn't give the behaviour expected, as the second call would still be through the abstract implementation.

Comment: @JonHanna: I hadn't noticed the expectation that the second call would *also* use the concrete version. Will edit.

Answer (score 30):

You need to define classes as:

```
public abstract class AbstractFunctionality:IFunctionality
{
    public virtual void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Abstract stuff" + "\n");
    }       
}

public class ConreteFunctionality:AbstractFunctionality
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Concrete stuff" + "\n");
    }
}
```

As you have not overriden Method() in ConreteFunctionality, the run time environment executes Method() associated with AbstractFunctionality object as it cannot apply dynamic polymorphism here. Introducing `virtual` and `override` makes the run time environment to execute the overriden method in child class.

Comment: Nice answer; but I would introduce the term "hiding", which describes the OP's original code, and note that hiding a method without the "new" keyword results in a compiler warning.

Answer (score 14):

You are missing `virtual` and `override` keywords. Without this you don't get virtual functions.

You can mark `Method` in AbstractFunctionality as `virtual` and mark the `Method` in `ConreteFunctionality` as `override`. As mihirj has shown.

Similar issues tackled in - [Why are C# interface methods not declared abstract or virtual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621410/why-are-c-sharp-interface-methods-not-declared-abstract-or-virtual)