# Calling Base Class Method using Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, reflection.emit

I have set up my code to define a type, set the parent type as well as implement an interface. The problem I am having is that when I go to create the type it says that it cannot find the method implementations for the interface even though those methods are implemented on the parent type. From what I have seen you need to define pass through methods for a situation like this, here is my code to do that:

```
    public interface IService<TDto, TId>
{
    Task<TId> CreateAsync(TDto entity);
    Task<bool> DeleteAsync(TId id);
    Task<bool> UpdateAsync(TDto entity);
    Task<List<TDto>> GetAllAsync();
    Task<TDto> GetAsync(TId id);
    TDto Get(TId id);
    Task<IEnumerable<TDto>> GetAllPagedAsync(Int32 page, Int32 take);
    Task<Int32> GetCountAsync();
    Task<object> GetForIdsAsync(TId[] ids, Int32? page = null, Int32? pageSize = null);
    object GetForIds(TId[] ids, Int32? page = null, Int32? pageSize = null);
    Task<bool> DeleteForIdsAsync(TId[] ids);
    Task<List<TDto>> CloneEntitiesAsync(List<TDto> dtos);
    Task<IList> GetForTypesAndIdsAsync(List<string> types, List<object[]> typeIds);
    Task<object> GetByConditionsAsync(Query query);
    Task<object> ExceptIdsAsync(TId[] ids, Int32? page = null, Int32? pageSize = null);
    bool Merge(TDto dto);
}

public Type[] CreateServiceType(Type dtoType, Type entityType, ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
        {
            string namespaceName = string.Format("Services.{0}", ProfileNamePlural);

            TypeBuilder iserviceTypeBuilder =
                moduleBuilder.DefineType(
                string.Format("{0}.I{1}Service", namespaceName, ClassName), 
                TypeAttributes.Interface | TypeAttributes.Abstract);

            var baseIServiceType = typeof (IService<,>).MakeGenericType(dtoType, entityType);
            iserviceTypeBuilder.AddInterfaceImplementation(baseIServiceType);

            Type iserviceType = iserviceTypeBuilder.CreateType();

            var baseType = typeof(AService<,,>).MakeGenericType(dtoType, entityType, typeof(Guid));

            string serviceClassName = string.Format("{0}.{1}Service", namespaceName, ClassName);

            TypeBuilder serviceTypeBuilder =
                moduleBuilder.DefineType(serviceClassName, TypeAttributes.Public);

            serviceTypeBuilder.SetParent(baseType);

            serviceTypeBuilder
                .AddInterfaceImplementation(iserviceType);

            var repositoryType = typeof(IRepository<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);

            ConstructorBuilder ctorBuilder =
                serviceTypeBuilder.DefineConstructor(
                    MethodAttributes.Public,
                    CallingConventions.Standard,
                    new[] { repositoryType });

            var baseConstructor =
                baseType.GetConstructor(
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance,
                    null, 
                    new[] { repositoryType }, 
                    null);

            var ilGenerator = ctorBuilder.GetILGenerator();

            // Generate constructor code
            ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);                // push "this" onto stack. 
            ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, baseConstructor);
            ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            DefinePassThroughs(ref serviceTypeBuilder, baseType, baseIServiceType);

            return new[] { serviceTypeBuilder.CreateType(), iserviceType };
        }

private void DefinePassThroughs(ref TypeBuilder typeBuilder, Type baseType, Type iServiceType)
        {
            var virtualMethods = iServiceType.GetMethods();
            foreach (var imethod in virtualMethods)
            {
                var method = baseType.GetMethod(imethod.Name);
                var paramTypes = method.GetParameters().Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToArray();

                var passThroughMethod =
                    typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
                    method.Name, 
                    MethodAttributes.Public, 
                    CallingConventions.Standard,
                    method.ReturnType,
                    paramTypes);

                var il = passThroughMethod.GetILGenerator();
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                for (var i = 0; i < paramTypes.Length; i++)
                {
                   il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, i + 1); 
                }

                il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, method, null);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(passThroughMethod, imethod);
            }
        }
```

When I try to create the type instance I get this error: "Signature of the body and declaration in a method implementation do not match." What am I missing here?

Comment: Are the classes or the method generic? Because in a vanilla scenario, the generated IL seems to be different (i.e. I get a `call` instead of a `callvirt` in a generic method)

Comment: Can you provide the complete code?

Comment: I've updated the code, its not everything, but I'm hoping it illistrates what I'm trying to do and what types of classes are being used. I've also put the Interface being implemented at the top.

Comment: the base class and most of the methods are generic

Comment: I tried changing it to call instead of callvirt though and it still gave me the same response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> even though those methods are implemented on the parent type.

Since the parent type is already implementing the interface, the derived type does not need the explicit pass throughs (you might need to declare the parents' implementations of the interface as virtual though).

Have a look at that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3621600/1698246

Comment: The methods are virtual on the AService class and when I don't define the pass throughs I get an error saying that the interface methods are not defined.

Comment: @ThePaxBisonica: I have tested this without getting such an error (.NET 4.5). The likelihood of someone being able to spot the problem will be higher if you show a complete example that repros the error.