# Error after upgraded to .Net 4.0

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, upgrade

we have and enterprise application running for last about 10 years. and we have upgraded it from .Net 1.1--> 2.0 -->3.5 and finally 4.0. these upgrades happened  over the years. All upgrades were smooth without any issues. but since we have upgraded to 4.0 we started getting error with event ID 1000 and 1026.

here is complete error log
>
>

> Faulting application name: BnBXMLLogger.exe, version: 6.30.38.0, time stamp: 0x4e6107bc
>
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdbdf
>
> Exception code: 0xe0434352
>
> Fault offset: 0x0000b727
>
> Faulting process id: 0x145c
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01cca50544bb4f4c
>
> Faulting application path: D:\BnB\BNBR_Build\bin\BnBXMLLogger.exe
>
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
>
> Report Id: 8cb72654-10f8-11e1-9a7c-00505690237e

Comment: Is this the only error information you have? By seeing the Faulting application name I assume it's a windows application?

Comment: yes its a windows application. and I have other EXE also when started I get event ID 1000,1024,1026 just saying unhanded exception nothing more.

Comment: Have you tried running a debug build, and attaching a debugger against it?

Comment: its coming on production. Cant attache debugger there. on development and testing no issues. We are thinking of opening a with Microsoft but before that want to make sure everything is fine from application side.

Comment: Does you're application use resources from filesystem, database, web.config or anything else? Have you checked if these resources are available and accesible?

Comment: Yes we use those resources.But If any of these resources are not available then I Think we should get a message like "resource unavailable" I am not getting any of message like this. And why this is happening after upgrade to 4.0.

Comment: Are both your development machines, aswell as production 64 bit or 32 bit? Or do we have mixed bitness.

Comment: both are 64bit machines. but my application is in 32 bit only.

Comment: @sandeep: Did you seriously change nothing but upgrade your projects to 4.0 and redeploy?  Seems like a waste.  Did you *install* 4.0 on the production machine?

Comment: NET 4 is not an upgrade of .Net 3.5
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620474/microsoft-net-compatibility

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham we changed other part of program we have som WCF API that we have changed. not the exe that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

To find out where the error is, I would suggest adding an [unhandled exception handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) to your code. That should give you the opportunity to catch the exception and log the stack trace, etc.