# Cannot Install Microsoft .NET 3.5 on Windows XP

Tags: .net

[new case after solving [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620474/microsoft-net-compatibility]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620474/microsoft-net-compatibility)

I used VS2010, and target for .Net 2.0 (VB.Net Windows Form application)
I ask my XP clients to install .Net 2 or 3.5

This week one of my clients re-installed his XP. I guess that Windows update installed there .Net 4.

He cannot install .Net 3.5 now, because he gets the following message -

```
Setup has detected that the Service Pack version of this system is newer than the update you are applying.
There is no need to install this update.
```

But there is a need!

- Can he uninstall .Net 4 ?
- how? Using ControlPanel | addRemovePrograms?
- and then install .Net 3.5 and later .Net 4 ?

**Solution:**

Solving [Setup has detected that the Service Pack version of this system is newer than the update you are applying. There is no need to install this update.]

You can try to unistall .Net 4 versions, using ControlPanel | addRemovePrograms
and then install .Net 3.5, and later also .Net 4.

If you do not manage to uninstall .Net 4 in this way, You can use a special removal tool. You can find more instructions about this tool in the following links -

1. .NET Framework Cleanup Tool User's Guide -
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx
2. Updated versions of .NET Framework cleanup and verification tools that work with the .NET Framework 4
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/13/10012778.aspx
3. How to remove .Net Framework 2.0, 3.0 4.5 -
   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ssizNQ0YPk

Comment: What's your question ?The post seems to contain question along with answer.

Comment: If the .Net 4 was installed during windows-update, can he uninstall it using ControlPanel | addRemovePrograms?  will it break other utilities?

Comment: I cannot tell if its possible in Windows XP,but in Windows 7,updates can be uninstalled using `View Installed Updates` section in `Programs and Features`.To uninstall an update select one update from the list and click on Uninstall.If you have Windows XP then you can try this approach to see if it's available.But in my opinion there is no need to uninstall the update.To make your project compatible with .NET 3.5 you should try changing the project configuration settings in `app.config`.

Comment: - I do no not want to re-pack my project [at this time . . .].

- My project needs .Net 2 or .Net 3.5 to run.

- The client cannot install .Net 3.5 because he already has .Net 4


- I will ask him to use the removal tool as @Balamurugan suggested. Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you sure he doesn't already have 3.5?  Maybe that is what the message is really trying to tell you.  2.0-3.5 installs side by side with 4.0.

Comment: According to a screenshot of his ControlPanel | addRemove.
He only has -
- [Microsoft .Net Framework 4 Client Profile] and
- [Microsoft .Net Framework 4 Extended]

Comment: If you don't want to repack your project,then I guess that the only workaround is to tell the user to uninstall the update.

Comment: You don't need to remove .NET 4.0!  Just download the stand alone installers for .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.5

Comment: Changed the title as the original one is ambiguous and does not match the problem at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is no need to uninstall the .Net4. .NET4 will support all lower versions.

Regarding Uninstall, Please use the **.NET Framework Cleanup Tool**.

Get it from here.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/01/8803442.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/13/10012778.aspx

Comment: There are differences! You can't run every .NET 2.0 on .NET 4.0!

Comment: But the removal links are usefull :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this Config to your app Config, then your application will works by any installed version of .NET framework, also it will be faster on .NET 4 and 4.5

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually install  the .NET frameworks seperately!

They all works independently from each other  ( on ASP.NET servers, you sometimes do need to pay attention to which .NET version is installed last)

Just google for them and download the stand alone installers.

Link .NET 3.5 : [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21)

```
 .NET 3.5 SP1: [link2][2]
```

...

Comment: But you cannot install .Net 3.5 when .Net 4 is already installed :(

Comment: Not true!  It has nothing to do with .NET 4.0. If the installer refuses to install, it's because you have a installer, that contains other programs too.  Find a stand-alone installer!

Comment: He tried using [http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22]
But he gets [Setup has detected that the Service Pack version of this system is newer than the update you are applying.
There is no need to install this update.]

any othe suggestion?

Comment: I just checked and no .NET is installed with the service packs of XP

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with this information:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/03/07/updated-what-to-do-if-other-net-framework-setup-troubleshooting-steps-do-not-help/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/08/28/net-framework-cleanup-tool-users-guide/

---

If this pages dissapear, I make a copy here:

- http://www.astrodreams.com/NET_FrameWork_Problems/Updated_what_to_do_if_other_NET_Framework_setup_troubleshooting_steps_do_not_help_–_Aaron_Stebners_WebLog.mht
- http://www.astrodreams.com/NET_FrameWork_Problems/NET_Framework_Cleanup_Tool_Users_Guide_–_Aaron_Stebners_WebLog.mht

If the Link to dotnetfx_cleanup_tool fail, I make also a Copy:

- http://www.astrodreams.com/NET_FrameWork_Problems/dotnetfx_cleanup_tool.zip

---

I SOLUTIONED DOING THIS IN MY WINDOWS XP - I HAVE VARIOUS WINDOWS IN MY PC AND XP FOR MY WORK VERY GOOD AND HAVE MANY PROGRAMS INSTALLED -:

I run the - http://www.astrodreams.com/NET_FrameWork_Problems/dotnetfx_cleanup_tool.zip -, and reinit windows, and install NET framework 3.5 and 4.0, and all OK!!!

NET Framework 3.5 Install the 2 Version of NET Framework

Here a copy of Net Frame Works 3.5 and 4, full:

- http://www.astrodreams.com/NET_FrameWork_Problems/dotnetfx35.exe
- http://www.astrodreams.com/NET_FrameWork_Problems/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe

Good day...